# Adding EditText to the dialog box

Tags: android

I have a Dialog window like the one shown in picture, and I have requirement of adding one EditText(to take quantity) next to every item, any possible ways to achieve this...?

[image: want to add EditText next to every item]

I have tried creating seperate view and setting it to AlertDialog, but getting single edittext at bottom..

Is there any possible ways that I can add EditText next to every item in the checklist, bec items here are populating from one one Array Items[], with

```
      DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener itemsDialogListener = 
      new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                selectedItems.add(Items[which]);
            else
                selectedItems.remove(Items[which]);
                                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                            for(CharSequence item : selectedItems)
                        stringBuilder.append(item + ",");

                            selectItems.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    };

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(this);
View v1=li.inflate(R.layout.itementry, null);//itementry view has one EditText
builder.setTitle("Select Items");
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colours, checkedItems, itemsDialogListener);
builder.setView(v1);    //By setting this line only one EditText is visible at 
                              the bottom of alert dialog.   
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can design your own view (xml layout) and set it to dialog box by using `setContentView()` method.

For example:

```
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layoutdialog);

 dialog.setView(R.layout.layoutdialog)   // for Alert dialog
```

Comment: i think this should be setView(R.layout.layoutDialog);

Comment: @N-JOY check this [Android custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) and search for setContentView().

Comment: ya okk i thought you were mentioning it for alertDialog. as AlertDialog.Builder class has method setView(layout);

Comment: Yes you are right about for alertDialog. I have updated answer. thanx

Answer (score 3):

```
     final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     final EditText input = new EditText(this);
     alert.setTitle("Enter the Number of Items");
     alert.setView(input);
     //final String s=input.getText().toString();
     alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
     {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
      {
        int i=arg2;
        values[i]= input.getText().toString().trim();
      }
     });
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Paresh Mayani is right. I've done this as same what he told. Like create one XML layout in that layout place your Edittext, spinners, textviews and etc...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/titleText1"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="115dp"
    android:layout_y="11dp"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="textPersonName" android:id="@+id/personText2" android:layout_y="66dp" android:layout_width="200px" android:layout_x="115dp"></EditText>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

and use this layout in your alertDialog builder create. Like

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(yourActivity.this);
        View v1=li.inflate(R.layout.alertDialogLayout, null);
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_get);
        builder.setView(v1);
        builder.setTitle("Something like your opinion");
```

And, also refer these links

1) [Custom AlertDialog](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/custom-alertdialog.html)

2) [Custom AlertDialog - 2](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/05/create-custom-dialog-using.html)

Comment: Yes SPK, it works but actually i want to add edittext next to every item, if I set builder.setView(view), I'm getting it at the bottom of checklist,,

Comment: @user1065490 See my edited Answer and refer those links. It may be helpful for you. And, don't forget to accept anyone of the answer which was you give accurate answer.

Comment: Yes SPK, it works but actually i want to add edittext next to every item, if I set builder.setView(view), I'm getting it at the bottom of checklist,, Actually the items on the popup are populating from one ArrayList... What I'm doing is,                          AlertDialog.Builder builder   = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v1=li.inflate(R.layout.itementry, null);
    builder.setTitle("Select Items");
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colours, checkedItems,  itemsDialogListener);
  builder.setView(v1);

Comment: I can't understand. Exactly what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edt = new EditText(this);
    edt.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});
    AlertDialog.Bulider altBx = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    altBx.setTitle("My dialog");
    altBx.setMessage("Welcome, Please Enter your name");
    altBx.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    altBx.setView(edt);

    altBx.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
      {
          if(edt.getText().toString().length()!=0)
          {
              //do anything
          }
          else 
          {
            //any msg
          }
      }
    });
    altBx.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
      {
          //any msg
      }
    });
  altBx.show();
```